# Logger.php throwing PHP errors

Tags: add-on, php, error

I'm getting some issues with some EE php errors, i believe its related to the EE Zoo Triggers Add On, but im finding it really tricky to debug and get the feeling I may be searching in the wrong place.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice    
Message: Undefined index: timestamp    
Filename: libraries/Logger.php    
Line Number: 121

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice    
Message: Undefined index: log_id
Filename: libraries/Logger.php
Line Number: 127

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'year' in 'field list'
UPDATE `exp_developer_log` SET `year` = NULL, `month` = NULL, `count` = '0', `viewed` = 'n', `timestamp` = 1354016532 WHERE `log_id` IS NULL
Filename: libraries/Logger.php
Line Number: 128
```

There is a little more info, error lines etc on a ticket in the devotee forums but i wanted to put it out to the EE community, see if any of you guys have come across similar errors and might be able to help resolve

Here is a little more info on what we have investigated so far:

> Im running EE 2.5.3 & PHP 5.2.17. Its triggered when I add the achieve
>   or categories list tags:
>
> ```
> {exp:zoo_triggers:categories    
>     channel="tours"  
>     path="{structure:page:uri}/region"   
>     show_counter="yes"   
>     style="list"
> }
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> {exp:zoo_triggers:archive    
>     channel="blog"   
>     path="/blog/archive"  
>     type="monthly"   
>     style="list"
>  }
> ```
>
> I use stash so these calls i from
>   within Stash set / append tags etc. Only other strange issue is that
>   it some cases (when logged in) it loads in the first instance and then
>   breaks on refresh or when clicking through to an archive link for
>   example, then the error persists. Clearing the ee cache or removing /
>   reassigning the structure listing resolves for that first visit again.
>
> ...
>
> It’s somewhat strange because the function where the errors occur must
>   be directly called, and that isn’t so in Zoo Triggers nor in the
>   version of Stash that I’m currently testing. Can you do a project
>   search on: ->developer( So we can have a better look what add-ons are
>   calling the function directly.
>
> ...
>
> Its odd, only references i can find are from the ee core:
>   system/expressionengine/core/EE_loader.php - line 136
>   system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Form_validation.php - line 438
>   system/expressionengine/libraries/Logger.php - line 186
>   system/expressionengine/modules/search/mod.search.php - line 186
>
> ...
>
> Source  http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-triggers/viewthread/7935

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome :) Try to avoid just linking to another thread - instead rewrite the question here with as much info as possible (e.g. EE version and PHP version, and anything else you covered in that thread). That will enable us to help you better.

Comment: Ok great, on it!

Comment: @SamHibberd It looks as though you wrapped this up on the Devotee forum. Would you mind posting the resolution here and marking it as accepted so that people will be aware that this is resolved? You can accept your own answers after a certain cut-off point, I'm not sure exactly when that kicks in.

Comment: (Alternatively you could accept Adrian's answer if that was what helped you pinpoint the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to diagnose PHP errors is to dig into the code and report the culprit. Do this:

Open `system/expressionengine/libraries/Logger.php`

At line 120 (right before your first error message), add this:

```
if ( ! isset($duplicate['timestamp']))
{
    debug_print_backtrace();
    exit;
}
```

Now taking a look at that particular part of the EE code, I really can't see what would cause those PHP errors you're seeing. Some code is trying to create a developer log entry and making a mess of things. It's likely to be an EE bug.

At least this should help you figure out what add-on is responsible for the problem!

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your input,  I do always get a little stuck when it comes to some of the very generic looking EE errors. Found Triggers using a depreciated function set_gmt(), probable cause?

Comment: Quite likely. Still, EE shouldn't be spewing PHP errors, so there's probably an EE bug at play here too. But if you can get Triggers upgraded/fixed it should solve the problem. Send them the output of that backtrace so they can easily see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Ok Great, thanks, and the EE bug: wheres the best place to report EE bugs now?

Comment: @Sam Hibberd the Ellislab EE big tracker is here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/